# How can I install MySQL 5.7.9 to Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: ubuntu, mysql, ubuntu-14.04

I tried to install with these inscturctions, but installation installed version 5.5.

```
$ sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
$ sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:ondrej/mysql-5.7
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```

http://tecadmin.net/install-mysql-5-on-ubuntu/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The PPA repository does not contain any packages for mysql 5.7: There are no deb files. Just take a look with your browser:

- http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/mysql-5.7/ubuntu/pool/main/m/mysql-5.7/

And on the status page it actually says:

```
 mysql-5.7 38 weeks ago
 Failed to build: amd64 i386
```

So at least for this ppa you are out of luck ;-(

Therefore I also suggest also using the original source at mysql/Oracle:

- See Mohit's answer for the short version.
- For the long version: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-apt-repo-quick-guide/en/
- Note that there is a more recent version of the config deb. Install that one: `dpkg -i mysql-apt-config_0.6.0-1_all.deb`
- The site might ask you to sign on or register. It's Oracle after all...

Then the this version should show up (5.7 is GA since 5.7.9 so 5.7.10 should be fine):

```
apt-cache show mysql-server=5.7.10-1ubuntu14.04
```

If it does install via:

```
apt-get install mysql-server=5.7.10-1ubuntu14.04
```

Note that you might have to clean up other dependent packages beforehand.

Comment: It worked, however I had to call apt-get update before it recognized that package.

Comment: This is outdated: Oracle offers a deb package for installing MySQL 5.7 and keeing it up o date.

Answer (score 15):

First visit https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/repo/apt/ to find the most recent version of the package.  The below version will be out of date by the time you read this.

**Please run below command:**

```
package=mysql-apt-config_0.8.11-1_all.deb
wget http://dev.mysql.com/get/$package
sudo dpkg -i $package
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```

Originally you needed to install `mysql-server-5.7` but with the more recent package, it is just `mysql-server`

Comment: This installs  5.7.8-rc, how can I install GA version ?

Comment: This should be marked as the correct answer!

Comment: probably need to run `mysql_upgrade --force` after you do this.  I did when I realized `mysqldump` was broken and that got it working again.

Comment: This now gives `W: GPG error: http://repo.mysql.com trusty InRelease: The following signatures were invalid: KEYEXPIRED 1487236823 KEYEXPIRED 1487236823 KEYEXPIRED 1487236823` when running `apt-get update`.

Answer (score 6):

Use [mohit's answer](https://serverfault.com/a/752081/355564), but refer to https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/repo/apt/ for the current mysql-apt-config. Click "Download" at the bottom. Then copy the link from "No thanks, just start my download." at the bottom

Comment: This might be better as a comment to Mohit's answer

Comment: sudo apt-get install mysql-server instead of mysql-server-5.7 when using the above instructions. Awesome Phil!